# In Python Regular Expressions, how can I disregard an expression inside a captured group?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<name>-<gender>-<age>.jpg
```

I want to be very liberal as far as what I accept. Requirements being:

1. The `<name>` component is required.
2. Must have the `.jpg` file extension
3. You may leave a component blank or leave it out entirely as long as the end result is one of the following permutations:

   - `<name>.jpg`
   - `<name>-<gender>.jpg`
   - `<name>-<gender>-<age>.jpg`

Examples of what is considered valid:

```
Beamin-M.jpg
Jean.jpg
Maria-F-23.jpg
```

I want to break down the each component of the string using regular expressions but I do not want to capture the dash (`-`). I tried using non-capturing groups but was not able to get the results I was looking for:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'([^\-]*)((?:\-)[^\-]*)?((?:\-)[^\-]*)?\.jpg')
>>> for d in (
...  'Beamin-M.jpg',
...  'Jean.jpg',
...  'Maria-F-23.jpg',
... ):
...  print r.match(d).groups()
...
('Beamin', '-M', None)
('Jean', None, None)
('Maria', '-F', '-23')
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of regex when there's a more logic-friendly solution readily available, so I'd try something like this:

```
from os.path import splitext    

test = '<name>-<gender>-<age>.jpg'

fname, ext = splitext(test) # works with names like 'xxx.yyy.jpg'
if ext in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
    name, gender, age = (fname.split('-') + [None, None])[:3]
```

Comment: I agree. You can make mistakes while writing a regex and will not realize it till very late. Regex needs a lot of positive and negative unit tests to make sure everything is right. My vote to you for pointing that out.

Comment: Great answer. Perfect example of when not answering the exact question deserves the green check.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your regex as:

```
r'([^\-]*)(?:-([^\-]*))?(?:-([^\-]*))?\.jpg'
```

Technically, you don't need to escape `-` in the character class `[]`, since it is the last in the class. But I'll just leave it there to be on the safe side.

Comment: You might want to replace `*` with `+`, otherwise it matches `Maria--23`

Comment: @thg435: I only fix the OP's attempt. Since he doesn't say anything about those cases, I assume that he is happy with the result except for the extra dash `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

You meant r'([^-]*)(?:(?:-)([^-]*))?((?:-)[^-]*)?.jpg')

Seriously, you are capturing the the dash because it is in outer captured parenthesis.